# How to make visible a layout programatically in fragment which is called in parent activity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-fragments

I have a layout defined in fragment.xml which is called in activity....
and I want to make it visible when a button in parent activity action bar is pressed which is in onOptionsItemSelected() .when i do this it make a error of null object reference....

fragment.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/relative_layout_current_job"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_current_job"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text_current_job"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_passenger_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    if (!mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen()) {
        // Only show items in the action bar relevant to this screen
        // if the drawer is not showing. Otherwise, let the drawer
        // decide what to show in the action bar.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.passenger_main, menu);
        restoreActionBar();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_job_confirm) {
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.action_job_confirm);
        RelativeLayout layoutCurrentJob = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_current_job);
        TextView status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_current_job_status_in_history);
        if((b.getText().toString()) == "job confirm") {
            status.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            b.setText("Job Started");
            layoutCurrentJob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            status.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            b.setText("jon confirm");
            layoutCurrentJob.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

mainmenu.xml

```
<item 
    android:id="@+id/action_job_confirm" 
    android:title="job confirm"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X12g0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do it for your fragment like this:

```
public class testFragment extends Fragment implements Handler.Callback{

    public final Handler handler = new Handler(testFragment.this);


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if (msg.what == 1) {
            //do your job here
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Call it from your activity like this:

```
testFragment frag = (testFragment) getFragmentManager()
.findFragmentByTag("Fragment_1");

Message ms = Message.obtain(frag.handler,1);
frag.handler.sendMessage(ms);
```

Comment: i have registered this method ... and there is an error showing ... "Method does not override method from its superclass"

Comment: let me give you full answer.wait

Comment: check it brother.it should help

Comment: application is crashing on when i pressed the button ....
it is giving error at this line .... Message ms = Message.obtain(frag.handler,1);

Comment: ah check your fragment tags.i think ur tag name is somethings different.

Answer (score 0):

On your code, Intializing

```
 RelativeLayout layoutCurrentJob=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_current_job);
```

is wrong. Because  the RelativeLayout you want to hide/show is part of your Fragment .you cannot initialized RelativeLayout by this.

It should be like as shown in below on your Fragment's onCreateView

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);
    RelativeLayout layoutCurrentJob=(RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.relative_layout_current_job);
}`
```

You can access widgets of your Fragment by below method

```
RelativeLayout layoutCurrentJob = (RelativeLayout )fragmentobj.getView().findViewById(R.id.img_one));
layoutCurrentJob.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: i updated my answer.use this method for other widget also.